# responsive layout using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <div class="jumbotron vertical-center bgpurpletextoffwhite"> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                  <img src="./assets/images/pmflogo-transparent.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                 <br>
                    <h3>Put Me First </h3>
                </div>
           </div>
```

This is my code. I want it to be responsive for all devices, but it is not acting responsive at present. What changes do I need to do in order to make it responsive.

Comment: You're missing two closing divs.

Comment: Please show us your output and describe how exactly you want it.

Comment: @vs_9 it would be easier if you included the relevant css rules (not the entire css sheet, just the classes being referenced here). It would save people having to download bootstrap, find the css, and then the relevant rules themselves if they aren't currently using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

It should be responsive if you are using bootstrap and your code is correct.  You are also missing 2 closing div tags `</div>` in your code.

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jaephoenix/h86mabte/

Your code should look like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center bgpurpletextoffwhite"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                <img src="s30.postimg.org/ozhb3rw8t/pmflogo.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <br />
                <h3>Put Me First </h3>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Close div for .row -->
     </div> <!-- Close div for .container -->
</div> <!-- Close div for .jumbotron -->
```

Comment: the distance between the image and text keeps changing as i re-size my browser window. i want the distance between the two to remain fixed/constant throughout any position.

Comment: The bootstrap *col* function is used for responsiveness.   Here is a nice explanation of how it works: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem. if you don't want it to change size, try using the col-xs-* on your divs or try giving your divs static width values in your css.

Comment: the link for the image that i have used is-  s30.postimg.org/ozhb3rw8t/pmflogo.png

Comment: What are you struggling with? Could you please provide a fiddle of your problem?